# Mock inner method using Rhino

Tags: c#, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have to do a simple unit test to check if `UpdateScript` is being called when `DateTimeChanged` is called. I would like to use mock for `UpdateScript` because it is a complex legacy code.

I tried using the Mocks and Stubs, but that is not working. Is there a way to mock just the sub method?

```
public void DateTimeChanged()
{
    if (isToggleOn)
    {
        this.UpdateScript();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `UpdateScript` is a virtual method? If so you can achive your goal with `partial mock` otherwise you have to use other mock frameworks like Typemock Isolator or MsFakes...

Comment: No, its not virtual... I will read on Typemock... Thanks alot :)